# Environment Variable does not update automatically on Changes in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, environment

**Context**

I am storing the current `Profile` inside the `Environment` of my `App`. This works great, however, sometimes `SwiftUI` does not automatically update the `View` when the `Value` of this `Environment Variable` changes.

---

**Code**

```swift
struct ProfileEnvironmentKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static var defaultValue: Profile? = nil
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    public var profile: Profile? {
        get { self[ProfileEnvironmentKey.self] }
        set { self[ProfileEnvironmentKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}

class ProfileViewModel: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = ProfileViewModel()
    
    @Published private(set) var profile: Profile?
    
    func activate(_ profile: Profile) { self.profile = profile }
    func logout() { self.profile = nil }
}

@main struct MedBlockxApp: App {
    @StateObject private var profileVM = ProfileViewModel.shared

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            RootView()
                .environment(\.profile, profileVM.profile)
        }
    }
}

struct RootView: View {
    @Environment(\.profile) private var profile: Profile?

    var body: some View {
        if let safeProfile = profile {
            Text(safeProfile.name)
        } else {
            Text("Select a Profile")
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Question**

- How can it be, that when logging out, the RootView does not update?

> Please note, that in the real `App`, the `LogOut Feature` is in a different `Tab` of a `SwiftUI` `TabView` than the `View` utilizing the `Environment`. However, as far as I know, the `View` should still update.

Comment: I am pretty sure you need to update it from inside a view for the environment value to change

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I just tried to move the `Environment Modifier` inside a `View` instead of using it in the `Main App`, however, the problem still persists.

Comment: I meant to not update it in ProfileViewModel

Comment: @JoakimDanielson How exactly do you mean that? Can you show it in `Code`?

Comment: You have put your `Profile` in the environment, not the `ProfileViewModel`.    You need something like ` RootView()
                .environment(\.profile, profileVM)` - Now you have an observable object in your environment and that object reference won't change- just the published property `profile`